# Inputbox in modal window not updating with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am triggering a modal with id `exampleModalCenter` using jQuery and Ajax as below

```js
$(".phAssignedDetails").click(function() {
  var sr = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("input[name='srNum']").val();
  var curStage = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("input[name='currentStage']").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "commonFiles/passFailHoldModal.php",
    data: {
      sr: sr
    },
    success: function(result) {
      $("#exampleModalCenter").modal('show');
      $("#currentSubStage").text(curStage);
    }
  });
});
```

HTML modal code inside `passFailHoldModal.php` as below

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Actions</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" id="assignOaForm" name="assignOaForm">
          <input type="text" id="tagSerial" name="tagSerial">
          <input type="text" id="currentSubStage" name="currentSubStage">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I am trying to change the value of `#currentSubStage` to the variable `curStage` after modal show. But it is not updating the value. Can someone help on this?

**Edit 1**

Here is the button

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark phAssignedDetails" name="phAssignedDetails" style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px; float: right;"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right" style="color:#3CE74E"></i></button>
```

Comment: First thing that cross my mind is if you tried to update the value of the field with: $("#currentSubStage").val(curStage); ?

Comment: The value of `curStage` can be some string. But when the modal triggered, the input box is showing empty

Comment: We need to see the html for phAssignedDetails

Comment: Change $("#currentSubStage").text(curStage); to $("#currentSubStage").val(curStage);

Comment: I just told you in the comment before, you should try to update the field value with `$("#currentSubStage").val(curStage);` in success callback of the ajax

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Edited the question

Comment: @AlexandruCorlan @Grumy: I tried to change to `.val(curStage)` too earlier. But not updating

Comment: Ok, then you should console.log(curStage) before your ajax to see the actual content of the var and to see if you are taking the DOM element the right way

Comment: I tried to `alert` the value of `curStage` before Ajax call and it is alerting the correct value

Comment: If you want this to work you need to check more things like, what is the actual value of curStage var before ajax, if you have a value there you sholud console log the actual value in the success callback before setting the value of the field. Also you should consider to check If you have just one element with that ID on the same page, this could be a issues also. Check also the console to see if you have some error there. How we are supposed to answer to your question is we don't see the entire code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text()` is not the right function. You're not trying to change the content of an HTML element like a div, but to assign a value to an input.

Here is how you should do it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#container", function() {
    var curStage = $("input[name='currentStage']").val();
    $("input[name='currentSubStage']").val(curStage);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
<input type="text" name="currentStage" value="foo">

<form method="post" id="assignOaForm" name="assignOaForm">
  <input type="text" id="tagSerial" name="tagSerial">
  <input type="text" id="currentSubStage" name="currentSubStage">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You are not answering to his question, you've just shown him how to update a field value without a modal and using the same ideas as in comments

Comment: Your code works. But logically mine also doing the same. Let me figure out

Comment: Then why you considered this as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```js
$(".phAssignedDetails").click(function() {
  var sr = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("input[name='srNum']").val();
  var curStage = $(this).closest(".card-body").find("input[name='currentStage']").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "commonFiles/passFailHoldModal.php",
    data: {
      sr: sr
    },
    success: function(result) {
      $("#exampleModalCenter").modal('show');
      $("#currentSubStage").val(curStage);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark phAssignedDetails" name="phAssignedDetails" style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px; float: left;"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right" style="color:#3CE74E"></i></button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Actions</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" id="assignOaForm" name="assignOaForm">
          <input type="text" id="tagSerial" name="tagSerial">
          <input type="text" id="currentSubStage" name="currentSubStage">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```